# Javascript: form won't clear when submitted

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, reset

I'm trying to get a form to clear after it is submitted, but none of the methods I've found are working.

**html**

```
<div id ="newcomment">
  <%= form_for([@thing, @good_comment], remote: true) do |f| %>
    <br>
    <%= f.text_area :text, :placeholder => "leave a comment...", class: "newcommentform" %>
    <div id="btn"><%= f.submit "Post", class: "btn btn-small", id: "postacomment" %></div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

**javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#postacomment").click(function () {
    $('.newcommentform').clearForm();
  });
</script>
```

Clicking on the submit button doesn't do anything, and in the web console I'm getting the following error:

```
TypeError: $(...).clearForm is not a function
```

I tried the other common methods as well. `$("#newcommentform')[0].reset();` returns the error

```
TypeError: $(...)[0] is undefined
```

and `$("#newcommentform.frm").trigger("reset");` doesn't return an error but doesn't do anything else either. What am I missing?

Comment: Would here be better to show the resulting HTML instead of showing the code to generate it.

Comment: Well, `clearForm` certainly isn't a function in jQuery.

Comment: $(':input','.newcommentform').not(':button, :submit').val('').removeAttr('checked').removeAttr('selected');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your clearForm() doesn't seem to exist, did you create a function to clear all the inputs and textarea in the form? Because clearForm() by itself is not a js function.

You can clear the form this way:

```
$("#postacomment").click(function() {
    $(this).closest('form').find("input[type=text], textarea").val("");
});
```

Comment: This doesn't account for radio buttons and the like

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$( '#newcommentform' ).each(function(){
    this.reset();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Enough to using this code:

```
$('.newcommentform')[0].reset()
```

because `$('.newcommentform')` is returned an array

you made a mistake writing :

```
$("#newcommentform')[0].reset(); // on ' and "
// you must write
$("#newcommentform")[0].reset();
```

Do you know when `.` and whem `#` is used in jQuery select. if not `.` is using with classname `$('.className')` and `#` is using with id `$('#id')`